# How to remove margin between rows in a dynamically populated table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want that there is no margin between the rows in the second example. All rows should have the same margin as example 1. Please note that I dynamically fill those tables, so I don't know how many rows are filled in or not.

```css
.marker-img-column {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  width: 20em;
}

.marker-img {
  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 275px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<h2>Everything is filled in</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      Name1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Materials Used:</td>
    <td>
      product 1, product 2, product 3
    </td>
    <td rowspan="10" class="marker-img-column"><img class="marker-img" src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/11/2500/1667.jpg?hmac=xxjFJtAPgshYkysU_aqx2sZir-kIOjNR9vx0te7GycQ" alt="Image marker name" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Compartment:
    </td>
    <td>
      Building
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fire rating:</td>
    <td>
      EI120
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Compartment type:</td>
    <td>
      Wall
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Materials:</td>
    <td>
      Material 1, Material 2, Material 3
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Penetration size (W x H):</td>
    <td>
      40 x 50
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pipe type / size:</td>
    <td>
      type / 50 mm
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wall tickness:</td>
    <td>
      55 mm
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Installation date:</td>
    <td>
      21/09/2023
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Comments:</td>
    <td>
      comment 1, comment 2, comment 3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h2>Some values are filled in</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      Name1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Materials Used:</td>
    <td>
      product 1, product 2, product 3
    </td>
    <td rowspan="10" class="marker-img-column"><img class="marker-img" src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/11/2500/1667.jpg?hmac=xxjFJtAPgshYkysU_aqx2sZir-kIOjNR9vx0te7GycQ" alt="Image marker name" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Compartment:
    </td>
    <td>
      Building
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Installation date:</td>
    <td>
      21/09/2023
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</html>
```

Also a CodePen document: https://codepen.io/SDG6/pen/JjwMOyZ

Comment: Your `<style>` element should - typically - be contained within the (missing) `<head>` element, the content to display in the web-page should be within the (missing) `<body>` element, and everything - except the `<doctype>` should be within the `<html>` element. While I imagine your browser is doing its best to rescue that malformed HTML, it's more reliable to write correct, valid HTML to minimise the surprises that come from the browser's "rescue." That said, this may not be the problem here.

Comment: note that your HTML markup is invalid. you placed a table directly within the HTML tags. A table must be placed within the body. you also miss a head.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but this is just for the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, the table rows on the left grow proportionally to fill the minimum height dictated by the image on the right.

Here's an alternative, replacing the table with css-grid:

```css
.grid {
  width: 700px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  gap: 1em 8px;
}
.grid .heading {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
}
.grid .image img {
  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 275px;
  height: auto;
}
.grid .description {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2
}
.grid .description {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  align-content: flex-start;
  gap: 0.25em 1ch;
}
```

```html
<h2>Everything is filled in</h2>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="heading">Name1</div>
  <div class="image">
    <img class="marker-img" src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/11/2500/1667.jpg?hmac=xxjFJtAPgshYkysU_aqx2sZir-kIOjNR9vx0te7GycQ" alt="Image marker name" />
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <span>Materials Used:</span>
    <span>product 1, product 2, product 3</span>
    <span>Compartment:</span>
    <span>Building</span>
    <span>Fire rating:</span>
    <span>EI120</span>
    <span>Compartment type:</span>
    <span>Wall</span>
    <span>Materials:</span>
    <span>Material 1, Material 2, Material 3</span>
    <span>Penetration size (W x H):</span>
    <span>40 x 50</span>
    <span>Pipe type / size:</span>
    <span>type / 50 mm</span>
    <span>Wall tickness:</span>
    <span>55 mm</span>
    <span>Installation date:</span>
    <span>21/09/2023</span>
    <span>Comments:</span>
    <span>comment 1, comment 2, comment 3</span>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Some values are filled in</h2>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="heading">Name1</div>
  <div class="image">
    <img class="marker-img" src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/11/2500/1667.jpg?hmac=xxjFJtAPgshYkysU_aqx2sZir-kIOjNR9vx0te7GycQ" alt="Image marker name" />
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <span>Materials Used:</span>
    <span>product 1, product 2, product 3</span>
    <span>Compartment:</span>
    <span>Building</span>
    <span>Installation date:</span>
    <span>21/09/2023</span>
  </div>
</div>
```